# Text File needs to be read line by line and then used to search a CSV file

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, do-while, cat

Total newbie here.. sorry.

I have a `.txt` file with IP's (Line by Line):

```
195.678.333.23
54.221.67.1
32.221.67.2
32.221.67.3
56.221.67.4
32.221.67.5
243.221.67.6
23.221.67.7
34.221.67.8
34.221.67.9
```

(there about 200 IP's that I need to loop through)

I need to read each line and then search multiple csv files to find these IP's to see if they exist.

the CSV is as such:

```
3am452525-1;2021-08-25T07:49:03.188353+00:00;195.678.333.23;234.45.78.232;\"pass rscore=16\";bl@hotmail.com resolve=ok reverse=bl@hotmail.com routes= notroutes=alfgdfgd,pr_sdt_Spsdgsgdhidfhgd;sxdgdsgs.hotmail.com;ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;NOT;sdgsgm@dunog.df;ENV_RCPT:dgsgsgsg@{hotmial.com,ENV_RCPT_VERIFY:1;ATTACH_NAME:sdgdsgsgsof.pdf,ATTACH_MIME:application/pdf,ATTACH_TYPE:pdf,ATTACH_OEXT:pdf,ATTACH_CORRUPT:0,ATTACH_PROTECT:0,ATTACH_SIZE:20099;;;;;;sdgsg_fhdh_dfhdh;asrsar_asrar;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;df;8.12.0-2107140000;main-2108250046;;;;sdgsg;;;;none;none;rule=sdgsgs action=ssdgsg-sgddsgr Subject default="sdgs $reyey";rule=odfhddh action=add-header dfhdhdReason="$SpamReason";;;;;;SEND_QID:4363636363,SEND_PROFILE:mail,SEND_RCPTS:dhdfhh;1;1;default_uioyuouyo_RcptInOrg;30677;uMwaF_x-00m7xOj-rho8njCPLr_QKYh3;<B8967386-0450-4709-A382-66D68CE4F3A6@rtce-efax1>;"zdgddadyhadyhad";0.283;1;0.856;Fax-Tdhfdm@urydyd;sdhdfhdhdhfd
```

The IP exists in `$3` field of the CSV file, but if I find the IP then I want the entire line as the output.

Can anyone please help?

I have tired things like:

`cat /tmp/IPs_filename.txt | while read line; do grep ${line} csvlog.436334.csv; done`

But not helping.

Thanks

Comment: What is _in $3 field of the CSV file_?

Comment: Please use proper Markdown formatting for the code / data snippets.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: it contains IP, thats what am looking for in that file. There are 2 fields with IP's in it but its the 3 field in that CSV file example

Comment: `awk -F\; -vipfile=some_file_with_ips 'BEGIN { while (getline ip < ipfile) ++ips[ip] } $3 in ips' the_csv_file`

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek not getting any output here?

Answer (score 5):

`awk` seems simplest to me.

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{lst[$0]; next} $3 in lst{print}' IPs.txt csv
```

Comment: This will avoid issues with pattern ambiguities *and* make sure it's only checking the correct column.

Comment: I would add `next` into the `NR == FNR` body, but +1

Comment: Agreed and done!

Answer (score 2):

`grep -f <txt_file_with_ip_addrs> csv_file1 csv_file2 ...`

From `grep`'s man page:

`-f, --file=FILE   take PATTERNS from FILE`

Since the IP addresses contain periods (interpreted as "any character" in regular expressions), you probably also want to use

`-F, --fixed-strings   PATTERNS are strings`

so that the IP addresses are interpreted as literal strings rather than regex.

Comment: this does not work i had already tried this. but thanks

Comment: The difficulty here is only matching the IP in the 3rd column rather than anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, without loops: the key here is to use the `-f` option for grep, and the process substitution to formulate the patterns.

```sh
# read the ips into an array
mapfile -t ips < IPs.txt

# grep to find lines with ip in 3rd semicolon-separated field
grep  -E -f <(printf '^[^;]+;[^;]+;%s;\n' "${ips[@]}") CSV.csv
```

Comment: cat /tmp/IPs.txt | while read l; do echo $(grep $1) | awk -F';' '{ if( $3 == $l ) printf "\%s;\%s;\%s\n", $3, $10, $11}' csvlog.20211024.csv; done

Comment: can anyone help me correct this please?

Comment: i guess the grep dont work with Awk?

Comment: First: `echo $(some command)` is a "useless echo" -- you're capturing the output of the command and then printing it again, except unquoted so you're mangling the whitespace.

Comment: next: `grep $1` -- `$1` is the pattern (which should be quoted), and since there are no file arguments, grep will read input from stdin. But there's no input. Nevertheless, grep is patiently waiting for some. Are you intending to search for `$l` (the line you just read from the IPs file) in the `$1` file ?

Comment: next: the awk code is in single quotes. The shell variable will not expand in there. The way to pass a shell variable into an awk variable is with the `-v` option: `awk -F';' -v ip="$l" '$3 == ip {printf ...}'`

Comment: last: the goal is to do all this _without_ loops. With a loop, you're calling grep and awk separately for each line of the IPs file. For performance, you want to avoid shell loops if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the results in needed by using the following command:

```
cat /tmp/ip_files.txt | while read l; do grep ";$l;" csvlog.202110*; done | awk -F';' '{ printf "\%s;\%s;\%s\n",  $2, $3, $5}' > /tmp/results.txt
```